# Не получается добавить информацию в базу данных с помощью PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Создал таблицу и пытаюсь занести в неё данные из формы. 
Данные не заносятся. 
К базе данных подключен.

[image: База и код]

```php
<?php
  require 'configDB.php';

  ?>
  <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ФИО"><br>
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Возраст"><br>
    <input type="text" name="registration" placeholder="Дата регистрации dd.mm.yyyy"><br>
    <input type="text" name="contract" placeholder="Номер договора"><br>
    <input type="text" name="competitions" placeholder="Соревнования"><br>
    <input type="text" name="primary_sport" placeholder="Основной спорт"><br>
    <input type="text" name="rank" placeholder="Разряд"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>    
  </form>

  <?php
  /* Statement Handle */
  $STH = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO clients(name, age, registration, contract, competitions, primary_sport, rank) VALUES(:name, :age, :registration, :contract, :competitions, :primary_sport, :rank)');

  $STH->execute(array (
    'name' => $name, 
    'age' => $age, 
    'registration' => $registration,
    'contract' => $contract,
    'competitions' => $competitions,
    'primary_sport' => $primary_sport,
    'rank' => $rank));

?>
```

Comment: 1. Код надо вставлять __текстом__. 2. Где определены переменные `$name`, `$age` и т.д.?

Comment: @Andy_Frost добавьте $info = $STH->errorInfo();
print_r($info); в конце, чтобы увидеть ошибку. Скорее всего нет некоторых столбцов в БД.

Comment: Переменные действительно не определил.  'name' => $_GET['name'] и все заработало. С помощью  $info = $STH->errorInfo(); print_r($info); отыскал ошибку в формате даты, которая не пропускала форму целиком.